# web scraping in R, a strange span class associated with an email

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape emails from the following html line

```
<p><span>E-mail address:</span><a title="&#xA; Link to email address&#xA;  
  "href="mailto:joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com">joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com</a></p>
```

Now, I don't know why this span class is proving so difficult for me.

I am using R but am not really sure how to go about solving this issue.

```
email <- html_text(
    html_nodes(doc, ?????)
```

Here is my current scraper that I am using

```
scrape <- function(x){
doc<-read_html(x)
author <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.art_authors'))
year <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.year'))
journalName <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.journalName'))
art_title <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.art_title'))
volume <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.volume'))
page <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, '.page'))
email <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, xpath = "//a[@class = 'email']"))
email2 <- html_text(html_nodes(doc, xpath = "//a[@class = 'ext-link']"))
    Author = ifelse(length(author)==0, NA, author)
    Year = ifelse(length(year)==0, NA, year)
    Journal_Name = ifelse(length(journalName)==0, NA, journalName) 
    Art_Title = ifelse(length(art_title)==0, NA, art_title)
    Volume = ifelse(length(volume)==0, NA, volume)
    Page = ifelse(length(page)==0, NA, page)
    Email = ifelse(length(email)==0, NA, 
    ifelse(length(email)==1, email, paste(email, collapse=" ; ")))
    Email2 = ifelse(length(email2)==0, NA, 
    ifelse(length(email2)==1, email2, paste(email2, collapse=" ; ")))
row<-cbind(Author, Year, Journal_Name, Art_Title, Volume, Page, Email, Email2)
}
```

Comment: Please make this [a reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What have you tried? What's going wrong? What's strange about the `span` class, since the `span` element in this HTML doesn't have a class?

Comment: yes, thats my problem, the span does not have a class so I really dont know how to pull it.

Comment: The way you get information from an HTML element is going to depend on the code you've written—such as whether you're using XPath vs CSS selectors. If you don't include your code, we don't know how you're trying to do this.

Comment: thanks, I went ahead and updated my post with my code

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `rvest::html_attr()` to select 'a' tag:

```
library(rvest)
doc <- read_html('<p><span>E-mail address:</span><a title="&#xA; Link to email 
address&#xA; "href="mailto:joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com">joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com</a></p>')

doc %>% html_node('a') %>% html_attr('href') %>% str_remove('mailto:')

## > doc %>% html_node('a') %>% html_attr('href') %>% str_remove('mailto:')
## [1] "joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way would be to choose `<a>` tags that have "mailto:" in the `href=` attribute. here's how you would do that

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
doc <- read_html('<p><span>E-mail address:</span><a title="&#xA; Link to email address&#xA;  
                   "href="mailto:joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com">joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com</a></p>')

html_nodes(doc, xpath='//a[starts-with(@href,"mailto:")]') %>% html_text()
# [1] "joeschmoe123@goodtimes.com"
```